# Running expo app in production mode always renders same app and code changes don't have any effect

Tags: react-native, expo

I am trying to build my expo app in production mode with the command

```
npx expo start --no-dev --minify
```

However any code changes don’t have any effect on the build. I assume the build is somewhere cached but even doing [these cache clearing](https://docs.expo.dev/troubleshooting/clear-cache-windows/) it still renders the same app.

Any help is highly appreciated.